# Realm under Unix

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, netbeans-7

first of all: please excuse my english. It's not my natural tongue.

I have a problem with a JDBC-realm and the consequences. First I'll show you the part of the web.xml relevant to this problem:

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>user/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>userConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User-Sites</web-resource-name>
        <description>Seiten fuer den normalen User</description>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/faces/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Alle Gruppen duerfen zugreifen</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>twiburealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>Normaler Anwendungs-User</description>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <description>Administrator</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

As you can see I tried different parts of URL-Pattern and (not shown here) all different kinds of welcome-page. If I start the Application the Login-Page is shown as expected. When I enter a invalid user/password combination the Error-Page is shown. But when I enter a vild combination I have 2 different results.

On windows it works as expected
on Unix a 403-Error is shown that I have no permission

I use jdk 7-05, GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and JSF 2.1 on both systems. JDBC-, JNDI-, Pool-, Realm and all is the same and the user is read successfully from the MySQL-Database. All names and URLs are entered in the same mode. Even lower- and Upper-Case are the same.

I have really no idea why I get the 403 under Unix. Any ideas?

Thanks and regards

Comment: Please, reformat your question. Nobody is going to try to fix that for you. After reformatting it will be easier to understand what you want.

Comment: Yes, I saw it by myself. Sorry. It's my first question here and I have to learn how to format

Comment: Is there any output in glassfish' server.log file that relates to this?  Maybe the realm isn't configured correctly on that server?

Comment: Not really. All server-log-entries are the same with one difference:

`[Web-Security] hasResource isGranted: true`


This is the second last line. All others are equal and shows that the realm is correct. These 3 lines shoes that. They are before the one showed before:

`    JDBC login succeeded for: Willi groups:[admin, user]`
`    JAAS login complete.`
`    JAAS authentication committed.`

Comment: Perhaps the mapping of groups to roles?  This is either in glassfish-web.xml, or maybe you depend on the "Default Principal to Role Mapping" setting on the server's security properties?

Comment: Yes, I have on both server the "Default Principal To Role Mapping" checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. So if someone has the same problem: under Unix you have to define the file "glassfish-web.xml". Mine has the following content:

```
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <group-name>admin</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <security-role-mapping>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <group-name>user</group-name>
    </security-role-mapping>
    <class-loader delegate="true"/>
    <jsp-config>
        <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
            <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
        </property>
    </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Under windows this file is not needed.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

The sun-* naming convention for glassfish deployment descriptors have all been deprecated or eliminated since Oracle took the helm, and replaced with glassfish-*.

This includes both the file names and the root XML element names.

To my knowledge (which is not certain), this is not an issue of windows vs unix, but rather by version of the glassfish software.

Comment: I know about the renaming from sun-* to glassfish-*. But I run the same version of glassfish on both machines. It's 3.1.2.2 and that's why I talk about a difference between Win and Unix.